# How to test HTMLImageElement.onload with jasmine + karma and Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

I want to write tests for an Angular project that I'm working on but I'm an absolute beginner when it comes to testing (theory-wise), for instance, I have a service that I sincerely have no idea how I should test. This service is simply a container where information specific to the customer using the program (like the company logo, address, etc.) is stored for later retrieval by other components. However, it has a routine that loads the logo image file using `HTMLImageElement` and transforms it to a data URL using `HTMLCanvasElement` like such:

```
const image = new Image
image.onload = function(event) {
  const self = <HTMLImageElement> this
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
  canvas.width = self.naturalWidth
  canvas.height = self.naturalHeight
  canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(self, 0, 0)
  logoInstance._dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.9)
}
```

For now, I just want to write a test that checks that the image was loaded and the data URL was stored successfully; something like:

```
it('...', () => {
  expect(logoInstance.dataUrl).toBeTruthy()
}
```

But the test sometimes fails (with `Expected '' to be truthy`) and sometimes pass. I think it is because the `onload` function is called asynchronously, and when the test fails it's because the image hasn't finished loading yet by the time the test is evaluated. However, even if I use `async` on the `beforeEach` function that kicks in the routine that I want to test, it still fails.

So my question is, how can I test a service that internally uses `HTMLImageElement.onload` to asynchronously load an image? Is there a way to evaluate the test only *after* `onload` has been called? I'm including below the complete code of what I have come up with after several attempts:

**customer-info.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'

class Logo {

  private _dataUrl = ''

  get dataUrl(): string {
    return this._dataUrl
  }

  setImage(image: HTMLImageElement): void {
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
    canvas.width = image.naturalWidth
    canvas.height = image.naturalHeight
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(image, 0, 0)
    this._dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.9)
  }
}


@Injectable()
export class CustomerInfoService {

  readonly logo = new Logo

  load(): void {
    const logoImage = new Image
    logoImage.onload = this.getOnImageLoadedCallback(this.logo)
    logoImage.src = './assets/images/customer-logo-lq.jpg'
  }

  private getOnImageLoadedCallback(logo: Logo): (event: Event) => void {
    return function(event) {
      const self = <HTMLImageElement> this
      logo.setImage(self)
    }
  }
}
```

**customer-info.spec.ts**

```
import { CustomerInfoService } from './customer-info'
import { async } from '@angular/core/testing'


describe('CoreModule.CustomerInfoService', () => {
  let service: CustomerInfoService = null

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    service = new CustomerInfoService
    service.load()
  }))

  it(
    'Should load the logo image and compute its data URL', 
    () => {
      expect(service.logo.dataUrl).toBeTruthy()
    }
  )
})
```

Thanks so much for your time and help.

---

### Update

After reading a little bit more about jasmine and angular, I understand now that my attempt of using `async` with `beforeEach` was correct, but for some reason, the behavior of my test doesn't change -it still fails sometimes and passes others. So I tried to do the following:

#### 1. fakeAsync and tick

I tried using `fakeAsync` instead of `async` which, as I understand, forces all asynchronous calls to be synchronous, but requires the use of `tick` to indicate that the image loading has finished. I refactored my test but got an exception that read `Error: Cannot make XHRs from within a fake async test` which makes sense since `HTMLImageElement.src` probably uses XHR asynchronous calls to load the image file. So I can't use this method with the current state of `CustomerInfoService`.

#### 2. DoneFn and Spies

I found out that `beforeEach`, `beforeAll` and `it` take an instance of `DoneFn` as an argument which can be used to indicate that the evaluation has finished and it's time to evaluate the next test. So I came up with the idea that I could use spies to intercept calls to `Logo.setImage` and invoke `DoneFn` after it is finished. Apparently doing something like `spyOn(...).and.callThrough().and.callFake()` doesn't work. So I tried doing this:

```
describe('CoreModule.CustomerInfoService', () => {
  beforeEach((done: DoneFn) => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        HttpClientModule
      ],
      providers: [
        CustomerInfoService
      ]
    })
    service = TestBed.get(CustomerInfoService)

    const setImageBackup = service.logo.setImage
    spyOn(service.logo, 'setImage').and.callFake((image) => {
      setImageBackup(image)
      done()
    })

    service.load()
  })

  it('...', () => {
    expect(service.logo.setImage).toHaveBeenCalled()
    expect(service.logo.dataUrl).not.toBeNull()
  })
})
```

However, I get yet another exception; this time stating `Cannot set property '_dataUrl' of undefined`, which makes sense, since `setImageBackup` does not have anything defined for `this` since it's not a method of any instance, just a function. Still, I believe this is the approach that could work for my case, maybe if I try spying on `HTMLImageElement.onload` instead? However, even if this approach works for me, I feel like I'm doing something wrong here -that I'm still missing something. I hope this information let's you understand better what my problem is and what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Interesting problem.  You mentioned you tried to wrap the 'it' callback function in an async, but did you also use 'whenStable'?  You would have to refactor your test to use the Angular TestBed testing helper, since it is a method available on the fixture object. The whenStable promise should resolve after your async callback is done.  Good docs here: https://angular.io/guide/testing#async-test-with-async

Comment: I didn't try using `whenStable` because technically this is a service, not a component, so I'm not using `TestBed.createComponent` to get a fixture.

Comment: I did try using `TestBed.get` however, but this doesn't return a fixture.

Comment: I thought of another approach.  Your service is creating DOM elements, but where? It seems to need to have a component that this service is injected into in order to have a template to add elements to. So how about using a TestWrapperComponent in the service test, just to wrap around the service and provide that template?  I set up a StackBlitz to test this out, but since I haven't worked with images like this I have no idea what your template should look like to make this work.  Can you fill in the details?  https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-q-53163776?file=app%2Fcustomer-info.spec.ts

Comment: The DOM elements don't need to be injected into any template, I'm only using the `HTMLImageElement` and `HTMLCanvasElement` interfaces to read an image file and convert its contents to a data URL string. If I were to use your approach, I could make the `Logo` class a component with an empty template only so that I can get a fixture and use `whenStable()` to finally make `async` work. But, wouldn't a component with an empty template technically be considered a service?